# form: how to autofill fields based on value in relation-dropdown

Tags: forms, pre-populate

I am afraid I am a bad coder, so I ask for a little help here. I went through answers, but I do not understand enough to go on.

I must make a form, one of the fields is a drop down, and before the user processes the form, the form must auto-fill in values of certain fields. I have got that working with a relationship field, but that gives a list with titles. I need one specific field.....

I tried Select2  http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/select2 as fieldtype which seems better than the relationship field, because I think I can select another field, not just the title. But the syntax of the MYSQL query confuses me. And I do not know how to do the auto-population.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Please update your question with your code. That'll help.

Comment: Hansl, were you ever able to resolve this? If so, you can answer your own question for future visitors.